# how to find php apiurl path location?

Tags: php

I'm stuck with finding the actual file(?) or a function from the following code lines...

I was able to find the "index.php"... 
however, what is the "Tickets/Ticket/ .... I don't see any file after that or such phrase in the "index.php"....

=============================

```
$apiUrl = 'https://cnc-h.com/sup/api/index.php/Tickets/Ticket/';
$ch = curl_init(); 
//based on the department switch from the on/off switch...
if($dept==1){
    $nagiosDept = $this->dept1ID;
}else if($dept==2){
    $nagiosDept = $this->dept2ID;
}
```

=============================

please help. 
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php   
    $apiUrl = 'https://cnc-h.com/sup/api/index.php/Tickets/Ticket/';
    $path=explode(".php/",$apiUrl);
    echo $filename=basename($path[0]).".php";
?>
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/664707)**

Comment: Hello @Dave thank you for your comment. 
I was able to find the actual swift code file <index.php> from the file manager. 

<?php
// Interface Declarations
define('SWIFT_INTERFACE', 'api');
define('SWIFT_INTERFACEFILE', __FILE__);

if (defined("SWIFT_CUSTOMPATH"))
{
 chdir(SWIFT_CUSTOMPATH);
} else {
 chdir('./../__swift/');
}

require_once ('./swift.php');
?>

how can I go deeper to find what the "Tickets/Ticket" from?